# How to validate fields after focus is changed in edittext in android

Tags: android

I am trying to validate my edittext field after focus is changed but it gives when the time of typing only.i.e, after entering one charecter I am used   below code

```
fname.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){//some validations}
```

But my requirement, in my form so many fields are there if we go for validation submition time its a risky one. so please help me.

Answer (score 5):

Add `OnFocusChangeListener` to your edit text

```
fname.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {


                    if (hasFocus) {
                          // If view having focus.
                    } else {
                          // If view not having focus. You can validate here
                    }
                }
            });
```